# RPC error when using @templewallet/dapp

Tags: smart-contracts, error, dapps

I'm getting this error when trying to execute a contract using temple wallet in my Dapp.

`Failed to send request to https://hangzhounet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations. Invalid request provided or RPC node is temporarily unreachable.`
[image]

Tried changing the RPC nodes in the Temple wallet itself to https://hangzhounet.api.tez.ie/, no difference except the text change in the link in the error.
Tried setting a new Tezos tool kit in the Dapp to a different RPC node, no difference either.

Using React and redux.

NPM versions:

```
"@taquito/beacon-wallet": "^11.0.2-beta",
"@taquito/signer": "^11.0.2-beta",
"@taquito/taquito": "^11.0.2-beta",
"@taquito/utils": "^11.0.2-beta",
"@temple-wallet/dapp": "^6.0.1",
```

This is the code for checking if the wallet is available:

```
useEffect(() => {
return TempleWallet.onAvailabilityChange((available) => {
  if (available) dispatch(setWallet(new TempleWallet(process.env.REACT_APP_NAME || 'MAVRYK')))
})
}, [dispatch])
```

This is where I connect to the wallet

```
try {
  if (!state.wallet) {
    dispatch(showToaster(ERROR, 'Temple Wallet not available', ''))
    throw new Error('Temple Wallet not available')
  } else {
    await state.wallet.wallet?.connect((process.env.REACT_APP_NETWORK || 'hangzhounet') as TempleDAppNetwork, {
      forcePermission,
    })
    const tzs = state.wallet.wallet?.toTezos()
    const accountPkh = await tzs?.wallet.pkh()

    dispatch({
      type: CONNECT,
      tezos: tzs,
      ready: Boolean(tzs),
      accountPkh: accountPkh,
    })
  }
} catch (err: any) {
  dispatch(showToaster(ERROR, 'Failed to connect TempleWallet', err.message))
  console.error(`Failed to connect TempleWallet: ${err.message}`)
}
```

And this is where I call the contract:

```
  const contract = await state.wallet.tezos?.wallet.at(delegationAddress.address)
  console.log('contract', contract)
  const transaction = await contract?.methods
    .registerAsSatellite(form.name, form.description, form.image, form.fee)
    .send()
  console.log('transaction', transaction)
```

Has Anyone encountered this problem / know how to address it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://rpc.hangzhounet.teztnets.xyz
is working for me.

const rpc_url = 'https://rpc.hangzhounet.teztnets.xyz';
const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(rpc_url);
const options = { name: 'TokenAppTest' };
const wallet = new BeaconWallet(options);